# Magento add to cart not working after cache

Tags: magento2, php, cache, addtocart

flurys.digifrizz.com is the site. In home page magento add to cart not working after cached. here is the `custom_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <update handle="1column"/>

  <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true" />
  <referenceContainer name="page.top" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.top" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="true" />

   <container name="root">
    <container name="header.container" as="HeaderContainer" label="Homeheader Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container-fluid px-0 clearfix">

<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/header.phtml" after="-"/>
</container>
<container name="firstsection.container" htmlTag="div"> 
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="firstsection" as="firstsection" template="Magento_Theme::html/home/firstsection.phtml" after="-" />
</container>
<container name="secondsection.container" htmlTag="div"> 
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="secondsection" as="secondsection" template="Magento_Theme::html/home/secondsection.phtml" after="-" />
</container>
<container name="featuredsection.container" htmlTag="div"> 
<block class="Digifrizz\Flurys\Block\FlurysAddToCart" name="featuredsection" as="featuredsection" template="Magento_Theme::html/home/featuredsection.phtml" after="-" cacheable="false"  />
</container>
        <container name="footer-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer" >
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
        </container>
             </container>
</page>
```

Here is the featured section

```
<!--Product Carousels-->
<?php
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();

$categoryId = 4; // YOUR CATEGORY ID

$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

                             ?>
                             <section class="container pt-5" data-aos="fade-up">
            <h2 class="mb-5">Introducing our new innovationsdd</h2>

            <!--Item carosel 1-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme pb-5">
<?php

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) 
{
    $imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
    ?>

     <!-- <div class="product-container">
                  <a href="<?= $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">

                     <div class="new-arrivals-image"><img src="<?= $imageUrl;?>"></div>
                     <div class="product-name"><span class="name"><?= $product->getName(); ?></span></div>
                  </a>
                  <div class="price"><span class="pt"><?= $product->getPrice(); ?></span></div>
               </div> -->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="<?= $imageUrl;?>" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4><?= $product->getName(); ?></h4>
                                <p><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> <?= $product->getPrice(); ?></p> 
                                <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
?>

<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 

    <div class="btn">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block ->getFormKey();?>">
    <button  type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="cta action tocart primary">Add to cart <i class="la la-shopping-cart"></i></button>

    </div>   
 </form>


                                <div class="quantity">
                                    <button class="less"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                    <div class="qty"><span>1</span></div>
                                    <button class="more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                </div>

                                <p class="text-center"><a href="#">View More</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
}
?>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Item carousel 2-->
            <?php $categoryId = 50; // YOUR CATEGORY ID

$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect(array('*'));

                             ?>
                             <section class="container pt-5" data-aos="fade-up">
            <h2 class="mb-5">Introducing our new innovationsdd</h2>

            <!--Item carosel 1-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme pb-5">
<?php

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) 
{
    $imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
    ?>

     <!-- <div class="product-container">
                  <a href="<?= $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">

                     <div class="new-arrivals-image"><img src="<?= $imageUrl;?>"></div>
                     <div class="product-name"><span class="name"><?= $product->getName(); ?></span></div>
                  </a>
                  <div class="price"><span class="pt"><?= $product->getPrice(); ?></span></div>
               </div> -->





                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="<?= $imageUrl;?>" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4><?= $product->getName(); ?></h4>
                                <p><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> <?= $product->getPrice(); ?></p> 
                                <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
?>

<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 

    <div class="btn">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block ->getFormKey();?>">
    <button  type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="cta action tocart primary">Add to cart <i class="la la-shopping-cart"></i></button>

    </div>   
 </form>


                                <div class="quantity">
                                    <button class="less"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                    <div class="qty"><span>1</span></div>
                                    <button class="more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                </div>

                                <p class="text-center"><a href="#">View More</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
}
?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= /* @NoEscape */ $product->getSku() ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
```

The form key is being cached. If cache is off its working fine.

Comment: I have added more detail to my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to dynamically bring in the form key before or during form submission.  You can fetch it using javascript.

`var $formKey = jQuery.cookie('form_key');`

*Updated*

https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml#L78-L82

In this example I have an onclick event that does a form submission and includes the form key as a parameter.

```
    require(["jquery"], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#register-interest").click(function() {
                if ($('#product_addtocart_form').valid()) {
                    var interestUrl = "<?= $block->getUrl('interest/index/submit', ['form_key' => $block->getFormKey()])?>",
                        interestName =  $("#interest-name").val(),
                        interestEmail =  $("#interest-email").val(),
                        interestProduct =  $("#interest-product-id").val(),
                        formKey = $.mage.cookies.get('form_key');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: interestUrl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        showLoader: true,
                        data: {
                            name: interestName,
                            email: interestEmail,
                            productId: interestProduct,
                            form_key: formKey
                        },
                    }).done(function (response) {                        
                        $("#register-interest-message").html(response.message);
                    }).fail(function (response) {
                        // console.log('Error. Try again.');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Then within controller

https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/master/Controller/Index/Submit.php#L62-L68

I validate form submission and form key

```
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if (!$request->isPost() ||
                !$this->isAjax() ||
                !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($request)) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __("There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.")
                );
            }
```

```
    /*
     *  Check Request is Ajax or not
     * @return boolean
     * */
    protected function isAjax()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        return $request->getServer('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') &&
               $request->getServer('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') === 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain in detail